# CSS dropdown menu not closing after click

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using the following tutorial: http://www.script-tutorials.com/css3-metal-menu-with-icons/

The problem is that when I click any element on the submenu, the submenu won't close. My app is using a jQuery UI tab to dynamically add a tab with the content as one partial view (mvc4) so that the app page isn't reloaded. I would like to hide the submenu when an item is clicked, how can i do that?

Comment: i have no idea where to start, the code is the same as the one on the link

Comment: Maybe you should look at how one would _bind_ a _handler_ to the _click_ event to _hide_ an _element_ in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, I would do something like traversing the parents if you know the exact depths, using a click event handler (where `e` is the event):
`$(e.target).parent().parent().hide(), etc`

If it could be dynamic, you can do it slightly less efficiently, but in one go:
`$(e.target).parents('.thedropdownmenuclass').hide()`

Answer (score 0):

The submenus are all located in a div with class named subs. You could hide that with JQuery.

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $(".subs").hide();
});
```

All clicks, anywhere should now hide the submenus or any other element with the class subs

Comment: it works but the menu wont work any more, no more sub menu after that, and if i use show(); they show up all the time